# CURL/WGET After a Delay

Tags: curl, web-scraping, wget

I understand that I can use CURL/WGET to get the contents of a page. But what if I want to get the page after it 'settles'? Or get the contents after a delay?

Example: a web page initially displays. After a time period (15 seconds, say), an element of that page changes or is updated (or even new content in that element). Can I capture that new element's content (or the entire page at that moment in time)?

Essentially, I want to access a page, wait 15 seconds, then CURL/WGET the content. Possible?

Comment: curl and wget don't know how to execute javascript, so no you cannot

Comment: @damian   Is there any other (automated) process that might accomplish this 'delayed scrape'?  Thanks.

Comment: take a look at phantomJs. I haven't used it and it was technically abandoned last year but it may be able to do what you want https://phantomjs.org/